# Automatic display of Server Manager - turn off

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to turn off the automatic display of Server Manager after each log on to the server (Windows Server 2008R2)? Can I do that for all servers that are domain members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this behavior, and this is done either by enabling the check-box Do not show me this console at log on or by setting a Group Policy.
If you have an Active Directory Domain Services environment, then you can set it using Group Policy Management Console.

To disable Server Manager automatic display after log on, follow these steps: In Server Manager, under the Server Summary section, enable the check-box beside “Do not show me this console at log on” and close the window.

To set it though Group Policy, then follow these steps: Go to Administrative tools then to Group policy management. In Computer Configuration for Default Domain policy (or any other policy setting e.g. for some OU), under Policies/Administrative templates/System find Server Manager and then enable “Do not display Server Manager automatically at log on”

Answer (score 2):

Why not go directly to the source of what is starting Server Manager, instead of putting up roadblocks to stop it afterwards? I found it easier to simply disable the task in Task Scheduler that starts Server Manager.

This was brought to my attention at: http://flamingkeys.com/2010/09/how-to-disable-server-manager-globally-on-server-2008-rtm-or-r2/

Just open Task Scheduler and navigate to:
Task Scheduler (Local) > Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > Server Manager

Then right-click on the task and select Disable.

Carl

Comment: Works in Server 2012 R2 as well.